# How to prevent position of a div from changing on resizing the screen

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```
<div id="PageContainer">
    <main>
      <section id="section1">
        <div id="section1width">
          <div id="section1Content">
            <p id="logo">Logo</p>
            <h1 id="h1Section1">Start tracking your life with MementoMori</h1>
            <p id="pSection1">Improves life check</p>
            <div id="buttonCenterSection1">
              <button>Try it</button>
            </div>
            <div id="bigTextSection1Container">
              <div id="bigTextSection1">
                <p id="pSection1"> Try mementomori now, and start lorem impusm lorem impusmlorem impusmlorem impusmlorem impusmlorem impusmlorem impusmlorem impusmlorem impusmlorem impusm</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="imgContainerSection1">
              <img id="imgSection1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"></img>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="section2"></section>
    </main>
  </div>
```

And this css

```
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section1{
    height:100vh;
    background-color: blue;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#section1width{
    width:60%;
    height:80%;
    background-color:purple;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    
}

#section1Content{
    width:80%;
    
    
}
#logo{
    text-align:center;
}

#h1Section1{
    text-align:center;
}
#pSection1{
    text-align:center;
}

#buttonCenterSection1{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#bigTextSection1Container{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#bigTextSection1{
    width:50%;
}
#imgContainerSection1{
   
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}

#imgSection1{
    width:75%;
    height:75%;
}

#section2{
    height:100vh;
    background-color:red;
}
```

The problem im facing is the following

[image]

Im trying to move the red box, to the yellow position. I did it with a magrin-top: 15vh, but the problem is that its not responsive, and if I change the screen size, it all gets messed up again.

How Do i Apply a margin top there without messing the structure when screen resizes?

Comment: Did not understand your requirement. Can you explain a bit more. I dont find any yellow box in your codepen demo

Comment: Is your problem - the image going out of the red box ?

Comment: Sorry @JithinB I might have done a bad explanation.  have updated the answer with a better image. I mean the red box of the image is the original position, and what is seen in the codepen , and in a 1920x1080 screen. But i want the context inside the redbox to be in the yellow box (Being partially outside of the purple box), but the point is, I want that for all the screen sizes, to mantain the same responsive position (Partially outisde of the purple box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not completely understand your requirement. Based on my understanding, I think you want the #section1Content to always stay at same position even while resizing. The issue is you have given the margin top in vh unit ( change based on window height). Try giving margin-top in px and try resizing.

```
margin-top: 200px;
```

[image]

This is what you require right ? Please try this and tell if this is what you wanted

Comment: Yes tahts what I mean, but when changing the screen size, the position is again messed up. I already tried that. It is possible to solve that without using mediaqueries?

Comment: With px it messes up too

Comment: Did you try giving it in px. Does the problem still occur ?

Comment: Yes, with px the same issue happens

Comment: Please check the image i Have uploaded ? This is what you require right ?

Comment: yes , exactly, and with the piece of code that you haave provided it looks fine in a big screen, but a resized screen makes this  https://i.imgur.com/NQa2Qbg.png . I would like to fix that without using media queries. But to be honest im not sure if that is possible

Comment: That is cos you have the given the height of #section1width as 80%. Means its taking 80% of the parent div ( section1) which is window height. So it resizes on changing window size , Give the height a fixed value in px. that would solve the  problem